# Self is nil when finding cell index path

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have this app that uses table views and I have two textfields in each tableview cell, cellTitle, and cellDescription. I want to know what the cell's indexpath is when either of the textfields have been edited. I have to pass that data to the viewController so I could save that data in my array of cells. When I test run it everytime, self is nil, which stops the code and i can't find a way to let the viewController know what cell number has been edited. Can someone help me find the cell indexPath for the edited textfield's cell?

**DashboardCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
protocol cellInfoDelegate {
    func tableCellInfo(title: String?, description: String?, cell: DashboardCell)

}

class DashboardCell: UITableViewCell {

    var indexpathInstance = IndexPath()

    //MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var cellDescription: UITextField!

    @IBAction func cellTitleEdited(_ sender: Any) {


        if cellTitle.text != nil {
            // ERROR HERE: self is nil
            cellInformationDelegate.tableCellInfo(title: cellTitle.text, description: cellDescription.text, cell: self)
        } else {
            cellTitle.text = "Untitled"
            cellInformationDelegate.tableCellInfo(title: cellTitle.text, description: cellDescription.text, cell: self)
        }


            }



    @IBAction func cellDescriptionEdited(_ sender: Any) {
        if cellDescription.text != nil  {
            cellInformationDelegate.tableCellInfo(title: cellTitle.text, description: cellDescription.text, cell: self)
        } else {
            cellDescription.text = "Add a description Here"
            cellInformationDelegate.tableCellInfo(title: cellTitle.text, description: cellDescription.text, cell: self)
        }
    }

    let cellInformationDelegate: cellInfoDelegate! = nil


    func setDashboardCell (cell: Dashboard) {
        cellTitle.text = cell.title
        cellDescription.text = cell.desccription
    }






}
```

**DashboardViewcontroller.swift**

```
import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, cellInfoDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    var events: [Dashboard] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var DashboardAdd: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!    
    @IBAction func DashboardAddA(_ sender: Any) {
        events.append(Dashboard(title: "Untitled", description: "Add A Description Here"))
        tableView.reloadData()
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let Dcells = events[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DashboardCell") as! DashboardCell
        cell.setDashboardCell(cell: Dcells)
        return cell
    }


    func tableCellInfo(title: String?, description: String?, cell: DashboardCell) {
        let indexPath = (self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row)!
        print("At row \(indexPath), the title is \(title), and the description is \(description)")

        if title != "" && description != "" {
        events[indexPath] = Dashboard(title: (title)!, description: (description)!)
        } else if title != "" && description == "" {
            events[indexPath] = Dashboard(title: (title)!, description: "")

        } else if title == "" && description != "" {
            events[indexPath] = Dashboard(title: "", description: (description)!)

        } else {
            events[indexPath] = Dashboard(title: "", description: "")

        }
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
        }

    func getCellNumber (cell: DashboardCell) -> Int?{
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        return indexPath?.row
    }

    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer =     UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:    #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }



}
```

Comment: Delegate must be a weak property. Change let cellInformationDelegate: cellInfoDelegate! to weak var cellInformationDelegate: cellInfoDelegate? Also you forgot to set a delegate property. After let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DashboardCell") as! DashboardCell add cell. cellInformationDelegate = self

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to change

```
let cellInformationDelegate: cellInfoDelegate! = nil
```

to:

```
var cellInformationDelegate: cellInfoDelegate! = nil
```

And then you will need to set the delegate in (cellForRowAt indexPath:) (excuse the psuedo code):

```
cell.cellInformationDelegate = self
```

You forgot to set the delegate, hence the delegate method is not being called. And you also didn't set the indexPath. So you will also need to add:

```
cell.indexPathInstance = indexPath
```

Comment: `cellInformationDelegate` should not be declared with `!`. And the cell should not have its own index path property. A cell never needs to know its own index path.

Comment: @rmaddy I wouldn't say never? What do you do if you need to know the indexPath for the cell that contains the textfield that called the delegate method? I've seen it many times and honestly have used it myself at times. How would you go about it? And yes the bang operator is not needed there cuz it is set to nil, but maybe he doesn't want it as an optional and doesn't want to have to unwrapped later

Comment: And why would the cell need to know the index path for the text field? The biggest issue is that the index path can be wrong if rows can be inserted, removed, or moved.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I definitely see a problem there. What would be the best solution then to track indexPath? This is out of curiosity. My answer was based on his question not to rewrite his code.